# Does WARN Client: Same path resource file:///tmp/programs95923.zip added multiple times to distributed cache matter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a large Apache Spark application running in Amazon EMR. I am trying to get rid of all the WARN messages in the logfile.

When our application starts, we make a ZIP file of the program's Python sourcecode, put it in a ZIP file called (here) programs95923.zip and provide the ZIP file to `spark-submit` with the `--files $ZIPFILE` argument (where `$ZIPFILE`) is the ZIP file that we create.

Hm. It seems we are also providing the ZIPFILE to `spark-submit` using `--py-files $ZIPFILE`. I'm not sure why we are providing it twice; I didn't write all of this code.

Questions:

1. Does this warning matter?
2. Should we only provide with `--files` or `--py-files` and not with both?

Comment: Hello @vy32 did the answer below clarify the question over the warning?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrosBiratsis. Unfortunately, not really. You are telling me what to do, but not why I am getting the warning. We are in fact just passing a .ZIP file, and only mentioning it once, and we are getting the warning.

Comment: hello @vy32 below I mention the part of code that is responsible for the check and which produces the warning. Each item passed with --files or --py-files is added to a collection called distributedUris this is a HashSet. If I understood well your questions was if that affect your job? The answer is it doesn't because the program will ignore a second item with the same name (will not add it to the distributedUris HashSet). As for the why are we getting this? is because as you wrote above you are passing the $ZIPFILE twice so just add it once and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

In the official Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) is stated:

> For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of
>  instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py
> files to the search path with --py-files.

Therefore only the `--py-files $ZIPFILE` parameter should be sufficient.

**UPDATE:**

As @vy32 already mentioned it seems that the message comes from Spark YARN client, and specifically in the line 437:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala

Moreover, the particular warning does not affect the execution since is not adding the new resource into the current resource list (distributedUris), please check lines 436 - 446. Therefore the mentioned *warning* will not have any impact on the execution of the Spark job.